# hosting web page on virtual machine

Tags: angularjs, apache, express, virtual-machine

I have a webpage which displays some results from an angular application and I would like to host it from a web server on my virtual machine. The purpose of it is to enable my team members to view the webpage daily. How do I go about doing this? I was suggested using node express or Apache. But I have no idea where to even start. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of options Apache being my recommendation. Here is a guide on setting up a [LAMP stack](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

If you are running windows look at using [XAMPP](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp) instead